# Dynamic placeholders on apex:inputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Firstly, is it possible to enter the HTML-placeholder dynamically? ({!object.name})

I have an input field on a Visualforce page, to enter a new account name.
There is a non-related object called label.

I would like to use a label record name as the HTML-placeholder value, for instance...

VF:

```
<apex:inputField id="label1" html-placeholder="{!label1.name}" value="{!addAccount.name}"/>
```

APEX:

```
label1 = [
SELECT
country__c,
id,
name
WHERE country__c = :thisAccount.Country__c];
```

I understand that this is not the correct apex syntax etc. but it should illustrate the point...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs ["Pass-through attributes aren’t supported in dynamic Visualforce."](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm)

If you are not able to set it dynamically you can always use javascript to set it on page load!